# Java - Get file as an input from Project folder

Tags: java, file, input, command-line, executable-jar

I have created a simple automated script for parsing my input files. My input file is a command line argument. My program works fine if I keep this input file in src folder.

But, I when I run my program by making it as an executable jar file I am getting file not found exception. Since executable jar file can be easily executed by operations team using the below command

```
java -jar parseData.jar Test.txt
```

Exception Details:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Test.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

so that my operations team can make use of it by simply giving the following command

I have tried the following code in my main but still there is no luck.

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getClass().getClassLoader();
URL url = classLoader.getResource(args[0]);
File inputFile = new File(classLoader.getResource(args[0]).getFile());
```

Now I get this exception details.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at parseData.main(parseData.java:31)
```

If some one done in this way please help me out.

Thanks

Comment: File file = new File("file.txt"); use this without class loader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not try to read from `classLoader.getResource`. This is only valid if the file you try to access is in your jar.

Instead, just use `new File(arg[0])`.

Comment: Nope it doesn't worked. I still get this exception `Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException:`

Comment: Is there a file called Test.txt in the directory you are running from?